# Powershell Script for Enabling Specific Site collection feature if not already activated

Tags: powershell, mysite

I need a PowerShell script for activating a specific site collection feature in every site collection of mysite if not already activated.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

If the are all under a managed path you can do something like this:

```
$sites = Get-SPSite https://mysiteurl/* -Limit ALL
foreach($site in $sites){
    Enable-SPFeature "name or GUID here" -Url $site.Url 
    $site.Dispose()
}
```

This will throw errors on sites where the feature is already activated, but since it is PowerShell the execution will continue for the other sites. You could use `ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` on `Enable-SPFeature` to not get the error output

Comment: doesn't work for me. powershell doesn't throw any error .feature doesn't activate

Comment: Do you pass in a correct URL base?